# Get & store digits from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a string of values like this:

```
=> "[\"3\", \"4\", \"60\", \"71\", \"49\", \"62\", \"9\", \"14\", \"17\", \"63\"]"
```

I want to put each value in an array so I can use each do. So something like this:

```
@numbers =>["72", "58", "49", "62", "9", "13", "17", "63"]
```

This is the code I want to use once the string is a usable array:

```
@numbers.each do |n| 
  @answers << Answer.find(n)
end
```

I have tried using `split()` but the characters are not balanced on each side of the number. I also was trying to use a regex `split(/\D/)` but I think I am just getting worse ideas.

The controller:

```
@scores = []
  @each_answer = []
  @score.answer_ids.split('/').each do |a| 
    @each_answer << Answer.find(a).id
  end
```

Where `@score.answer_ids` is:

```
=> "[\"3\", \"4\", \"60\", \"71\", \"49\", \"62\", \"9\", \"14\", \"17\", \"63\"]"
```

Comment: My question is, why are you getting a string like that? We very seldom see data like that, which makes me think you're getting it from a source that isn't written correctly. It looks like the output of `puts` or `inspect`, which isn't how you want to transfer data.

Comment: +1 to the Tin Man question. And also, you shouldn't iterate over array, it will generate N queries to database, instead, use: `Answer.where(id: @numbers)`

Comment: Yes, the attribute is storing an array as a string. Normally you wouldn't do this :D

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov `Answer.find` also works with arrays of ids, so `Answer.find(@numbers)` would work too. (See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find).)

Comment: @Ajedi32, yeah, good point, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

```
foo = "[\"3\", \"4\", \"60\", \"71\", \"49\", \"62\", \"9\", \"14\", \"17\", \"63\"]"
foo.scan(/\d+/) # => ["3", "4", "60", "71", "49", "62", "9", "14", "17", "63"]
```

If you want integers instead of strings:

```
foo.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) # => [3, 4, 60, 71, 49, 62, 9, 14, 17, 63]
```

If the data originates inside your system, and isn't the result of user input from the wilds of the Internet, then you can do something simple like:

```
bar = eval(foo) # => ["3", "4", "60", "71", "49", "62", "9", "14", "17", "63"]
```

which will execute the contents of the string as if it was Ruby code. You do NOT want to do that if the input came from user input that you haven't scrubbed.

Comment: The contents of the string originate from the system. Already scrubbed. I will try this.

Comment: All of your approaches work. I used scan since I like it better. Do you know of any advantages of scan and eval that would help decide which to pick? +1

Comment: @DDDD Scan is probably significantly faster in terms of performance.

Comment: Using `scan` works, but parsing it as JSON is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an array of JSON strings. You could probably use [Ruby's built-in JSON library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) to parse it, then map the elements of the array to integers:

```
input = "[\"3\", \"4\", \"60\", \"71\", \"49\", \"62\", \"9\", \"14\", \"17\", \"63\"]"

require 'json'
ids = JSON.parse(input).map(&:to_i)

@answers += Answer.find(ids)
```

Comment: This works as well. Although since @answers = [] it seems to be an array within an array. +1

Comment: Well crap, which is better then? the Tin Man or yours?

Comment: +1. I'd recommend going with this one, with a minor modification. `JSON[input].map(&:to_i)` is more concise. `JSON[input].map(&:to_i) # => [3, 4, 60, 71, 49, 62, 9, 14, 17, 63]`.

Comment: @DDDD That's pretty subjective. Tinman's answer using `scan(/d+/)` is probably faster in terms of performance since it doesn't bother parsing the text as JSON, and doesn't require loading an external library. The code I wrote, on the other hand, is probably more robust in that it's sensitive to malformed data in the string, and will error out rather than return a potentially incorrect result if the string contains invalid JSON. So I guess it depends on your exact requirements. Really though, the differences are pretty minor.

Answer (score 1):

In your code *n* is a String, not an Integer. The #find method expects an Integer, so you need to convert the String to an Array of Integers before iterating over it. For example:

```
str = "[\"3\", \"4\", \"60\", \"71\", \"49\", \"62\", \"9\", \"14\", \"17\", \"63\"]"
str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).each do |n|
    @answers << Answer.find(n)
end
```